# Does max_retries limit the quantity of "retries" when using acks_late&

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a task that looks like this (ofcourse the run method if more complex):

```
class SomeTask(celery.Task):
    max_reries = 3
    acks_late = True

    def run(self):
        print('some code')
```

I know that celery has acks_late and retry options. I need to use acks_late. So Im wondering: max_reries = 3 limit the quantity of "retries" just for retry() or for acks_late also.

I tried to find this in celery docs, but there was no information about that.

UPD It looks like no. I restarted my worker, so celery rerun my task. I did it 4 times and after all the task was done.
Maybe way I tested was not correct. It will be great if someone could answer this for sure, as  I told wrote, maybe the way I tested was not correct.